# Adding a general rule to label_suffix in Django forms

Tags: python, django, web

I added this snippet into my models.py to override Django form's default behaviour of adding ":" to form labels

```
from django.forms import BaseForm
orig_init = BaseForm.__init__
def BaseForm_init(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault("label_suffix", "")
    orig_init(*args, **kwargs)
BaseForm.__init__ = BaseForm_init
```

It has the intended result. But now I am trying, instead of appending '' (nothing), to append a linebreak 'br' so every label is followed by a line break. So the fourth line of the above snippet would look like

```
      kwargs.setdefault("label_suffix", "<br>")
```

This should have the effect of doing the below in a specific instance on all form items

```
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,label = mark_safe('LABEL_NAME<br>'))
```

instead it prints 
 as text on the html page... looking at the HTML source you can see why:

```
 <label for="id_hello">Hello&lt;br&gt;</label>
```

The python code is converting the triangular brackets into the html code for a triangular bracket which displays it as text.

How can I get it to print:

```
 <label for="id_hello">Hello<br></label>
```

Comment: have you tried `kwargs.setdefault("label_suffix", mark_safe('<br>'))`>?

Comment: @SohanJain can't believe I didn't think of that... Do you want to put that as an answer? It works.

Comment: Backwards incompatible changes in 1.6; BoundField.label_tag now includes the form’s label_suffix https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#boundfield-label-tag-now-includes-the-form-s-label-suffix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `kwargs.setdefault("label_suffix", mark_safe('<br>'))>?`